# jquery use of :last and val()

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to run the code from http://jsfiddle.net/ddole/AC5mP/13/ on my machine and the approach I've use is below or [here](http://pastebin.com/cADEuzX1).

Do you know why that code doesn't work on my machine. Firebug doesn't help me and I can't solve the problem. I think that I need another pair of eyes :(((

In firebug,console tab i don't get any error message. The problem is that I can't get the value of that input from the dialog box, after I press save button. The $('input:last').val() seems to be empty

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('.helpDialog').hide();
            $('.helpButton').each(function() {  
                $.data(this, 'dialog',
                $(this).next('.helpDialog').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,  
                    modal: true,  
                    width: 300,  
                    height: 250,
                    buttons: {
                        "Save": function() {
                            alert($('.helpText:last').val());
                            $(this).dialog( "close" );
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                            $(this).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
                })
            );  
            }).click(function() {  
                $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');  
                return false;  
            });  
        });  
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <span class="helpButton">Button</span>
    <div class="helpDialog">
        <input type="text" class="helpText" />
    </div>

    <span class="helpButton">Button 2</span>
    <div class="helpDialog">
        <input type="text" class="helpText" />
    </div>

    <span class="helpButton">Button 3</span>
    <div class="helpDialog">
        <input type="text" class="helpText" />
    </div>

    <span class="helpButton">Button 4</span>
    <div class="helpDialog">
        <input type="text" class="helpText" />
    </div>

    <span class="helpButton">Button 5</span>
    <div class="helpDialog">
        <input type="text" class="helpText" />
    </div>    </body>
```

Comment: What is happening on your machine? The pop-up don't display?

Comment: also, is there any error in the firebug console. Do you have all dependencies in the correct place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/AC5mP/16/)**

To display the text on save, I have modified your line `alert($('.helpText:last').val());` to this `alert($('.helpText', this).val());`

I have added one more dependencies on fiddler,

**http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js**

Now its working as expected.

### HTML:

```
<span class="helpButton">Button</span>
<div class="helpDialog">
    <input type="text" class="helpText" />
</div>
<span class="helpButton">Button 2</span>
<div class="helpDialog">
    <input type="text" class="helpText" />
</div>
<span class="helpButton">Button 3</span>
<div class="helpDialog">
    <input type="text" class="helpText" />
</div>
<span class="helpButton">Button 4</span>
<div class="helpDialog">
    <input type="text" class="helpText" />
</div>
<span class="helpButton">Button 5</span>
<div class="helpDialog">
    <input type="text" class="helpText" />
</div>
```

### JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.helpDialog').hide();
  $('.helpButton').each(function() {  
    $.data(this, 'dialog', 
      $(this).next('.helpDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,  
        modal: true,  
        width: 300,  
        height: 250,
        buttons: {
            Save: function() {
                alert($('.helpText', this).val());
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
      })
    );  
  }).click(function() {  
      $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');  
      return false;  
  });  
});
```